# Team foudation server

Tags: tfs

I have installed and configured TFS on my server, also I have created a project TEST in TFS. I want to ask how to add code to TFS server and then map it with code in mu local pc.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx

High level overview

1. Open visual studio
2. Connect to team collection/team project
3. Map the team project to a folder on your local pc
4. Get all the files if any from tfs
5. Add any files from your local workspace to TFS.

Comment: thank you, I have already done that, but how can I add users who can use TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Before you change permission levels for others, make sure that you have the right level of permissions.

1. Open the administrative context for your team project.
2. In the Security tab, under users, find your own name, and look at what groups you belong to and what permissions you have
3. If you aren't a project administrator, you need to be. Find someone who is, and have them add you.
4. Add user to a team project or a team, etc.

For detailed information you can refer to article below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb558971(v=vs.140).aspx